# Style dialog after click on MediaRouteButton

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

Hi can someone help me with styling dialog that appears after clicking on MediaRouteButton?
[image: Chromecast dialog]

There is a white text displayed on gray background which doesn't look good.

```
android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
```

is wrapped in parent with styles

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
```

(I know that I should use Toolbar here but it doesn't match my requirements)

which works good on MediaRouteButton which turns white, but it have no influence on dialog styles.

I tried to look at sample app provided by Google, but I haven't found anything that helps me. [Link to sample app styles](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/master/res/values/styles_castvideo.xml)

My current theme:

```
  <style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>//Blue
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>//dark blue
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>//blue
</style>
```

Comment: Did you made any progress to style the dialog correctly?

Comment: No, still no change

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found a solution that worked for me.

At first you have to set a custom MediaRouteDialogFactory on your MediaRouteButton

```
mMediaRouteMenuItem = CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(this, menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item);
MediaRouteButton mediaRouteButton = (MediaRouteButton) mMediaRouteMenuItem.getActionView()
mediaRouteButton.setDialogFactory(new ThemeableMediaRouteDialogFactory());
```

Cause the default MediaRouteDialogFactory will always create non themed Dialogs

```
@NonNull
public MediaRouteControllerDialogFragment onCreateControllerDialogFragment() {
    return new MediaRouteControllerDialogFragment();
}
```

which will lead to

```
public MediaRouteControllerDialog onCreateControllerDialog(
        Context context, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new MediaRouteControllerDialog(context);
}
```

but there is also a themed constructor [MediaRouteControllerDialog(Context context, int theme)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/MediaRouteControllerDialog.html#MediaRouteControllerDialog(android.content.Context,%20int))
which is not called from original MediaRouteDialogFactory.

So your ThemeableMediaRouteDialogFactory should be look like this

```
public class ThemeableMediaRouteDialogFactory extends MediaRouteDialogFactory {
@NonNull
@Override
public MediaRouteChooserDialogFragment onCreateChooserDialogFragment() {
    return new ThemeableMediaRouterChooserDialogFragment();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MediaRouteControllerDialogFragment onCreateControllerDialogFragment() {
return new ThemeableMediaRouteControllerDialogFragment();
}
}
```

with

```
public class ThemeableMediaRouterChooserDialogFragment extends MediaRouteChooserDialogFragment {

@Override
public MediaRouteChooserDialog onCreateChooserDialog(Context context, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new MediaRouteChooserDialog(context, R.style.CastChooserDialogTheme);
}
}
```

and

```
public class ThemeableMediaRouteControllerDialogFragment extends MediaRouteControllerDialogFragment {

@Override
public MediaRouteControllerDialog onCreateControllerDialog(Context context, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return  new MediaRouteControllerDialog(context, R.style.CastControllerDialogTheme);
}
}
```

Your themes/styles can also be customized

```
<style name="DarkDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/charcoal_grey</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/charcoal_grey_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/pumpkin_orange</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/dark_grey</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="CastChooserDialogTheme" parent="DarkDialogTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="mediaRouteChooserPrimaryTextStyle">@style/MediaRouteChooserPrimaryText</item>
    <item name="mediaRouteChooserSecondaryTextStyle">@style/MediaRouteChooserSecondaryText</item>
</style>

<style name="CastControllerDialogTheme" parent="DarkDialogTheme">
    <item name="MediaRouteControllerWindowBackground">@color/dark_grey</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/dark_grey</item>
    <item name="mediaRouteCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_dialog_close_dark</item>
    <item name="mediaRouteControllerTitleTextStyle">@style/Widget.MediaRouter.ControllerText.Title.Dark</item>
</style>
```